# Put Request throwing 401 [no body] Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, http-headers

I am trying to call an api to put a request but it is throwing a 401 unauthorized error. I have added all the necessary headers but still getting the same error. I just need another eye on this; Code below:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = getJsonExchangeHeaders();
    headers.setBearerAuth(BearerTokenUtil.getBearerToken());

    HttpEntity<PhoneNumberVerificationDto> entity = new HttpEntity<>(phoneNumberVerificationDto, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response;
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(URI.create(url), HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            log.info("Customer validation Success for MFA in IDP for: phone:{} with status: {}", phoneNumberVerificationDto.getPhoneNumber(), response.getStatusCode());
            return true;
        } else {
            log.error("Customer validation failed for MFA in IDP for: phone:{} with status: {}", phoneNumberVerificationDto.getPhoneNumber(), response.getStatusCode());
            return false;
        }
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        throw new RestClientException("Idp facade API error for user with phone number " + phoneNumberVerificationDto.getPhoneNumber(), e);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. Have you debugged this and looked at the Authorization header in your headers object?  Perhaps `BearerTokenUtil.getBearerToken()` is returning an empty string

Comment: @lane.maxwell yes, I have and it does return the bearer token.

Comment: In that case, try taking the contents of your body, headers, and URL and test it through postman, but the 401 usually indicates that it's missing authentication details